# VirtualBox/Vagrant stopped working after Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox

I was happily using Vagrant with VirtualBox for my laravel projects (Homestead) but after the Creators Update for Windows 10, VirtualBox stopped working - *vagrant up* was not throwing any errors and I was even able to *vagrant ssh* successfully but my web projects were unreachable from the browser.

Initially I was using VirtualBox v.5.1.14 but decided to update to the latest (which is v.5.1.22) - no luck whatsoever, so after reading the answers from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1199354/virtualbox-no-longer-running-in-win10-creators-update) I've downgraded to v.5.0.38

Now when I try to *vagrant up* this error is shown:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Resuming suspended VM...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "e5ac5ef8-07fa-412f-b59c-bfd745db047e", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to load unit 'cpum' (VERR_INVALID_FLAGS)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

p.s. I've already set *Host-Only Network Adapter* through preferences in VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve the issue was to "plug off" my virtual machine's state using [discard](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm4893), hoping not to lose any information... Now I'm on VirtualBox v.5.1.14 and will stick with it until all things work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update to Virtualbox **Version 5.2** to get my boxes running again.

and also need to reinstall git for windows 2.15.1.2-64 bit  and select the option **"use windows default console"** (cmd.exe) instead of **"MinTTY"**

With MinTTY the command :

```
vagrant ssh
```

will not show the bash command line.

using windows default Console worked.
see more possibe workarounds to this piont also in this [git issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9143)

**My** Working env:

```
  - Windows 10 - 1709 - Build 16299.125
  - vagrant 2.0.1
  - virtualbox 5.2.0
  - git for windows  2.15.1.2. 64 bit
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning off **`Hyper-V`** solved my problem.

Solution:

```
Control Panel -> Turn Windows Feature on or Off -> Uncheck Hyper-V
```

I had the same problem. My `vagrant up` stopped working after the Windows Fall Creators Update (1709). It worked after I turned off Hyper-V.

Current Working Environment:

```
- Windows 10 (1709)
- Vagrant 1.9.7
- VirtualBox 5.1.32
```